# Django-Kronos 0 tasks installed error

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to make a website.

models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
     ...
     end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name='end_date')
      Membership_status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)#1= active, 0=deactive, 2=refund status
```

I want to compare the end date to today, and if today is more recent, I would like to automatically make the membership status zero(0) (It is currently 1).

So, I used the Django-Kronos.

cron.py

```
from staff.models import Member
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import kronos

@kronos.register('* 1 * * *')
def the_task():
    today = datetime.date.today() 
    Member.objects.filter(end_date__lte=today).update(Membership_status=0)
```

I installed Django-Kronos and wrote the `kronos` in installed apps.

But, I have no idea how I implement the cron.py automatically every 1.a.m.
`('* 1 * * *')` means 1 a.m.  But it doesn't work.

**EDIT]**

I tried `sudo python3 manage.py installtasks` in linux(using putty). But, `0 tasks installed` happens.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py installtasks`?

Comment: I just tried. But the error happens `OSError: please specify user or filename to write'.`

Comment: Ah, I test on windows. `Kronos isn't tested on windows. In fact, does Windows even have cron?`  Then, if I just run `python manage.py installtasks` on Linux(using putty), does the cron.py run automatically?

Comment: Oh yea, that makes sense. Yes, if you ssh in to your server and run `python manage.py installtasks` it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried. But `0 tasks installed` happens. It is the same result without `import random`. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I changed the position of cron.py! Kronos collects tasks from cron modules in your project root and each of your applications. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, Julia. If you answered your own question you should consider posting an answer so if anyone else googles your error they will see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answerering my own question!

I changed the position of cron.py.
The official Kronos github says, 
'Kronos collects tasks from cron modules in your project root and each of your applications'

But, I solved the problem putting my cron.py in my app instead of the project root.